# Auto pointer for unsigned char array?

Tags: c++

I'd need a class like std::auto_ptr for an array of unsigned char*, allocated with new[]. But auto_ptr only calls delete and not delete[], so i can't use it.

I also need to have a function which creates and returns the array. I came out with my own implementation within a class ArrayDeleter, which i use like in this example:

```
#include <Utils/ArrayDeleter.hxx>

typedef Utils::ArrayDeleter<unsigned char> Bytes;

void f()
{
  // Create array with new
  unsigned char* xBytes = new unsigned char[10];
  // pass array to constructor of ArrayDeleter and
  // wrap it into auto_ptr
  return std::auto_ptr<Bytes>(new Bytes(xBytes));
}

...
// usage of return value
{
  auto_ptr<Bytes> xBytes(f());
}// unsigned char* is destroyed with delete[] in destructor of ArrayDeleter
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this? (Even using another "popular" library)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Boost has a variety of auto-pointers, including ones for arrays. Have you considered if std::vector is sufficient? Vectors are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory, and if you know the size and allocate memory ahead of time via `reserve()` or `resize()`, the location in memory will not change.

Comment: I had a look at boost and I think the scoped_array would do it. Thanks

Comment: @Gianluca: Why won't you use vector?

Comment: @GMan: sure, now i see it's a much better idea. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I then have to call a methods that takes unsigned char* as argument.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
.
.
.
legacy_function(&vec[0], vec.size());
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `std::basic_string<unsigned char>`? Or maybe `std::vector<unsigned char>`?

Comment: I then have to call a methods that takes unsigned char* as argument. Is there a way to access it from inside one of the containers you suggest? Will basic_string's method data() do it?

Comment: You could use the std::string '.c_str()' method, this returns a null terminated char* .

Answer (score -1):

1. You're talking about an array of `int`, not complex C++ types that have a destructor.
   For such an array calling `delete[]` is equivalent to calling `delete`. So there's no problem to use `std::auto_ptr`.
2. The method you suggest is very barbaric IMHO. You actually allocate memory twice: once for the needed array, and then you also allocate an instance of `ArrayDeleter`, which encapsulates the pointer to the allocated array.

The drawbacks of such a method are:

- Worse performance. Heap operations are heavy. Also they have significant memory overhead.
- Slower access. To access an element of your array via the `std::auto_ptr<Bytes>` the compiler will generate two indirections: one to get your `Bytes` object, and the other to access the element.
  In simple words: `std::auto_ptr` has a pointer to `Bytes` object, which has a pointer to the array.
- Worse error/exception consistency. Imagine what if the `operator new` fails to allocate the `Bytes` object. It'll generate an exception, which may be handled. But at this point you've **already** allocated the array. And this allocation will be lost.

I'd do one of the following:

1. If you're talking about an ordinary type - just use `std::auto_ptr<type>`. This should do the work. However you should check it with your compiler.
2. For complex types: you may create your own wrapper instead of the `std::auto_ptr`.
3. Another variant: similar to what you did. However you should get rid of the extra memory allocations and indirections.

Comment: Calling `delete` on a dynamically allocated array is ALWAYS UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR, even if it always seemed to work for you on all the compilers you tried.

Comment: delete[] is NOT equivalent to calling delete, even for POD. See 18.6.1.2 (Array forms) in the Standard: "void operator delete[](void* ptr) throw(); ...
Requires: ptr ... shall be the value returned by an earlier call to
operator new[](std::size_t) or operator new[](std::size_t,const std::nothrow_t&)"

Comment: This is exactly the reason why I've written "you should check it with your compiler."
Strictly speaking you're right. The standard says it's an undefined behavior. OTOH I said what *actually* happens. At least on MSVC compiler.

The reason why "delete[]" should be used instead of "delete" is not because we need to know how much memory should be freed - according this argument you'd have to pass the memory size into "free" function as well.
The reason is that when you used "delete[]" the compiler generates calls to d'tors of objects in addition to freeing the memory.

Comment: @valdo: But people want to program C++, not a specific variant of it. Relying on undefined behavior is bad.

Comment: @Valdo that's not true: when you use delete[] you deallocate the right amount of memory in the right form. Why do you suggest to rely on the eccentric behaviour of (some version of) a compiler, I don't know.